# C: Realloc() after reading second line in file results in garbage values

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc, fasta

I'm attempting to read sequences from a FASTA file into a table of structs that I've created, which each contain a character array member called "seq". My code seems to work well for the first loop, but when I realloc() memory for the second sequence, the pointer seems to point to garbage values and then the strcat() method gives me a segfault.

Here's the whole FASTA file I'm trying to read from:

```
>1
AAAAAAAAAAGWTSGTAAAAAAAAAAA
>2
LLLLLLLLLLGWTSGTLLLLLLLLLLL
>3
CCCCCCCCCCGWTSGTCCCCCCCCCCC
```

Here's the code (sorry that some of the variable names are in french):

```
typedef struct _tgSeq { char *titre ; char *seq ; int lg ; } tgSeq ;

#define MAX_SEQ_LN 1000

tgSeq* readFasta(char *nomFile) {

    char ligne[MAX_SEQ_LN];
    tgSeq *lesSeq = NULL;
    int nbSeq=-1;

    FILE *pF = fopen(nomFile, "r");

    while(fgets(ligne, MAX_SEQ_LN, pF) != NULL) {

        if(ligne[0] == '>') {
            /*create a new sequence*/
            nbSeq++;

            //reallocate memory to keep the new sequence in the *lesSeq table
            lesSeq = realloc(lesSeq, (nbSeq)*sizeof(tgSeq));

            //allocate memory for the title of the new sequence
            lesSeq[nbSeq].titre = malloc((strlen(ligne)+1)*sizeof(char));

            //lesSeq[nbSeq+1].titre becomes a pointer that points to the same memory as ligne
            strcpy(lesSeq[nbSeq].titre, ligne);

            //Now we create the new members of the sequence that we can fill with the correct information later  
            lesSeq[nbSeq].lg = 0;
            lesSeq[nbSeq].seq = NULL;

        } else {
            /*fill the members of the sequence*/

            //reallocate memory for the new sequence
            lesSeq[nbSeq].seq = realloc(lesSeq[nbSeq].seq, (sizeof(char)*(lesSeq[nbSeq].lg+1+strlen(ligne))));
            strcat(lesSeq[nbSeq].seq, ligne);

            lesSeq[nbSeq].lg += strlen(ligne);
        }
    }
    // Close the file 
    fclose(pF); 

    return lesSeq;
}
```

For the first line (AAAAAAAAAAGWTSGTAAAAAAAAAAA), lesSeq[nbSeq].seq = realloc(lesSeq[nbSeq].seq, (sizeof(char)*(lesSeq[nbSeq].lg+1+strlen(ligne)))); gives me an empty character array that I can concatenate onto, but for the second line (LLLLLLLLLLGWTSGTLLLLLLLLLLL) the same code gives me garbage characters like "(???". I'm assuming the problem is that the reallocation is pointing towards some sort of garbage memory, but I don't understand why it would be different for the first line versus the second line.

Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: A little [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) would probably help here. Hint: What is the value of `nbSeq` the first time you call `realloc`?

Comment: It will also be wrong each time you enter the `if(ligne[0] == '>')` branch. Not only first time

Comment: Note, After `strcpy(lesSeq[nbSeq].titre, ligne);`,  `lesSeq[nbSeq].titre` likely has a  `'\n'` in it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the first realloc gets the value of nbSeq as 0 which does not allocate any memory.

Replace

```
int nbSeq=-1;
```

with

```
int nbSeq=0;
```

Access the index with `lesSeq[nbSeq - 1]`

Answer (score 0):

Some programmer dude already pointed out that you do not allocate enough memory.

You also seem to expect some behaviour from `realloc` that will not happen.

You call `realloc` with `NULL` pointers. This will make it behave same as `malloc`.

> For the first line (AAAAAAAAAAGWTSGTAAAAAAAAAAA), ...= realloc(); gives me an empty character array that I can concatenate onto, but for the second line (LLLLLLLLLLGWTSGTLLLLLLLLLLL) the same code gives me garbage characters like "(???".

You should not expect any specifiy content of your allocated memory. Especially the memory location is not set to 0. If you want to rely on that, you can use `calloc`.
Or you simply assign a `0` to the first memory location.

You do not really concatenaty anything. Instead you allocate new memory where you could simply use `strcpy` instead of `strcat`.